# Custom JWT Auth with Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to setup authentication with JWT with Spring Security inside a Spring WebFlux application. I'm using a custom authorization scheme based on custom JWT claims. The problem I'm having is that when I try to invoke a secured endpoint authentication fails with `Authentication failed: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`.

Here is the `SecurityWebFilterChain` I'm using:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {

        return http {

            authorizeExchange {
                authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
            }

            oauth2ResourceServer {
                jwt {
                    jwtAuthenticationConverter = grantedAuthoritiesExtractor()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun grantedAuthoritiesExtractor(): Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {
        val jwtAuthenticationConverter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(MappingJwtAuthoritiesConverter())
        //               custom JWT -> Collection<GrantedAuthority>  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        return ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(): ReactiveJwtDecoder {
        val secretKey: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".toByteArray(), "HMACSHA256")

        return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey).macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256).build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtValidator(): OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {
        return OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> { OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success() }
    }

    fun jwtAuthenticationManager(jwtDecoder: ReactiveJwtDecoder): JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager {
        return JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(jwtDecoder).apply {
            this.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `MappingJwtAuthoritiesConverter`:

```kotlin
class MappingJwtAuthoritiesConverter : Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    companion object {
        private val WELL_KNOWN_CLAIMS: Set<String> = setOf("myCustomClaim")
    }

    override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): Collection<GrantedAuthority> {
        val authorities = jwt.claims.entries
            .filter { (key, _) -> key in WELL_KNOWN_CLAIMS }
            .map { (key, value) ->
                return@map SimpleGrantedAuthority("$key:$value")
            }

        return authorities
    }
}
```

I searched online but many JWT/Spring Webflux implementation hand-roll JWT validation and handling, and I'd rather use what's already offered by Spring under OAuth integration. Right now the only custom piece I'm using is the converter from JWT to `GrantedAuthority`, but I still can't get authentication to work.

With the following JWT:

```
header:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}

payload:
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1658474926,
  "exp": 1668478526,
  "myCustomClaim": "READ"
}
```

Encoded:
`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4NDc0OTI2LCJleHAiOjE2Njg0Nzg1MjYsIm15Q3VzdG9tQ2xhaW0iOiJSRUFEIn0.lh66pHMd_xvXAF2itblHeHbZReJQA5xkGLKqXZV6MjI`

The endpoint I'm trying to secure is defined as:

```kotlin
@RestController
class FooController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('myCustomClaim:READ')")
    @RequestMapping(
            method = [RequestMethod.GET],
            value = ["/foo"],
    )
    override suspend fun getFoo(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Got foo")
    }
}
```

Spring logs:

```
2022-07-22 09:43:35.138 DEBUG 508191 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [b7fe0c9e-1] HTTP GET "/foo"
2022-07-22 09:43:35.313 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2022-07-22 09:43:35.319 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatchers$1@3602a026
2022-07-22 09:43:35.319 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
2022-07-22 09:43:35.319 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/foo' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@2668fdab
2022-07-22 09:43:35.320 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization successful
2022-07-22 09:43:35.325 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [b7fe0c9e-1] Mapped to it.project.backend.controllers.FooController#getFoo(Continuation)
2022-07-22 09:43:35.665 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthenticationWebFilter      : Authentication failed: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
2022-07-22 09:43:35.694 DEBUG 508191 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [b7fe0c9e-1] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you adding a custom filter `AuthenticationWebFilter`

Comment: I added it because most articles I read on JWT auth with spring did, either way I get the same error with or without it.

Comment: Don read outdated blogs, read the spring documentation.

Comment: For the version I have here I followed https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html. Do you have any other pointers?

Comment: In the link you posted, please point me to where they add a custom filter

Comment: You're correctly pointing out that in the official docs they don't use a custom filter. However, even in that case I can't get auth to work, that's why I tried adding it.

Comment: well, then update your question with the correct code and steps to reproduce, as in what your request looks like and with the full spring security debug logs. And when i say correct code i mean not code from blogs and tutorials. Follow how the official documentation implements it and remove everything else that is NOT needed. I dont like lenghty discussions

Comment: also you dont need to disable all the other logins, they are disabled by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` instead of `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity` in the configuration bean. After fixing that everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the secret key you constructed your `jwtDecoder` with does not correspond to the signature of the token you posted and thus the token validation fails.

You can use https://jwt.io/ to check that.

Comment: Sorry, I mispasted the JWT. I do still have the same problem even with the correct JWT :(

Comment: For the key `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` the correct one will be `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4NDc0OTI2LCJleHAiOjE2Njg0Nzg1MjYsIm15Q3VzdG9tQ2xhaW0iOiJSRUFEIn0.Sg16pgJSiF8wEzceD1TbOjNb3W3ujKV1hRY-_gv4A9A` . Give it a try.

Comment: Just tied yours with the key you provided and got the same error